# When dropdownlist changes back to default value, it isn't changing the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdownlist that is getting repopulated when a user clicks on a radio button. In my code, you click the radiobutton and it is repopulating the dropdownlist properly and then my code recalculates the price based on the current selected value which gets set to the default value when the dropdownlist gets repopulated. The problem is that when I click on the radio button, the price should be recalculated as 0 because the default value is 0 but instead the value of the dropdownlist doesn't get changed to 0 and I can't figure out why.

Here is an example of the ajax code that works when a user changes that radio button value:

```
$("#doubleSpacingV").change(function () {
    // only goes off when it goes from unchecked to checked
    var modelData = {
        paperType: $("#paperTypeJList").val(),
        urgency: $("#urgencyJList").val(),
        numOfPages: $("#numOfPagesJList").val(),
        spacing: $('.spacingCheckBox:checked').val()
    };

    var spacingValue = $('.spacingCheckBox:checked').val()

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("NumberOfPagesList", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { id: spacingValue },
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            var items = "<option value=0>Choose Number of Pages/Words</option>";
            $.each(response, function (i, spacing) {
                items += "<option value='" + spacing.Value + "'>" + spacing.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#numOfPagesJList").html(items);
        }
    });
```

I inserted an alert at the end btw to check the value for the numOfPagesJList which should be 0 but it isn't getting updated correctly for some reason. Here is some similar code that should be the exact same and it is working properly:

```
$('#paperTypeJList').change(function () {
    var modelData = {
        paperType: $("#paperTypeJList").text,
        urgency: $("#urgencyJList").val(),
        numOfPages: $("#numOfPagesJList").val(),
        spacing: $('.spacingCheckBox:checked').val()
    };

    var typeValue = $("#paperTypeJList").val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("UrgencyList", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
        data: { id : typeValue },
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function (response) {
            var items = "<option value=0>Select the Urgency</option>";
            $.each(response, function (i, urgency) {
                items += "<option value='" + urgency.Value + "'>" + urgency.Text + "</option>";
            });
            $("#urgencyJList").html(items);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getNewPrice","Home")',
        type: "POST",
        data: modelData,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        success: function(response){
            document.getElementById('priceLabel').innerHTML = response;
        }
    });
});
```

I'm getting really frustrated with this bug. Can anyone please help?

Comment: I'm a bit lost. Do you mean you want to reset the selected index to 0?

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm being confusing. When I repopulate the dropdownlist with new values, it sets the selected value to the first item in the list and that item's value is 0

Comment: What do you want to do? To have the selected value set to ?

Comment: I want to reset the dropdownlist selected value to 0 after it gets repopulated

Comment: Buddy, in your first comment you said `it sets the selected value to the first item in the list and that item's value is 0`.Is that not what you want?

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I meant that it sets the selected text to the first item in the list but the value doesn't change from the previous value